# Creating quiz application - working with views

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a quiz application.
I have a normal Java class for a question and it looks like that:

```
public class Question {
    private String question;
    private LinkedList<Answer> answers;

    public String getQuestion(){
        return this.question;
    }

    public LinkedList<Answer> getAnswers(){
        return this.answers;
    }

    public Question(String question, LinkedList<Answer> answers){
        this.question = question;
        this.answers = answers;
    }

    public boolean checkIfCorrectAnswer(Answer answer){
        if (null == answer)
            return false;
        for (Answer i : answers){
            if (i == answer && answer.isCorrectAns())
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and an answer class that looks like this:

```
public class Answer {
    private String answerTxt;
    private boolean correctAns;

    public String getAnswerTxt() {

        return answerTxt;
    }

    public boolean isCorrectAns() {
        return correctAns;
    }

    public Answer(String answerTxt) {
        new Answer(answerTxt, false);
    }
    public Answer(String answerTxt, boolean correctAns){
        this.answerTxt = answerTxt;
        this.correctAns = correctAns;
    }


}
```

Now I want to make a view (xml file) that will show each question and it's options, I came to something close and this is the result:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".QuizActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textViewQuizTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textViewQuizQuestion"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewQuizTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewQuizQuestion"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_weight="0.04" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.04" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.04" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.04" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have two issues now - I didn't understand how do I attach a simple java class to a view, and the other problem is the "navigation" between the questions, when someone answer a question correctly is supposed to load the view again, but with a different "Question" in.

I tried to learn from activity/fragment tutorials but unfortunatly none of those that I checked pointed out my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you configure a xml layout to an Activity. Learn about Activity and with some logic you might use your xml layout, only if you always gonna show one question with 4 answer options (buttons). You probably should use another component like Radio Button or Spinner instead of 4 Buttons to get a better ui design. What you need is simple, but you'll have to learn about Activity and View before start anything.

Answer (score 1):

For the question on attaching a Java class to a view, I suggest that you create or get an instance of this class within your Activity class. For example, `Question question1 = new Question(<constructor args here>)`. Do this for every Question and Answer object.

For the question on navigation, you will need to implement an `onClick` listener on your buttons so that you will know when someone has submitted the answers by clicking one of the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a `ViewPager` to manage your quiz application. The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) has a sample application that you could start with.

I assume you would have a question set (i.e. a list of questions and answers). This question set could be used to populate the `ViewPager` and  the number of pages in the `ViewPager` can be specified using the size of the question set. I believe this would solve your "navigation problem".

For the other issue, you could dynamically inflate a layout based on the type of question and answer. You didn't provide enough information about your question and answer type/requirement, so I can't really make a better suggestion until I know the question type/requirement.

Let me know if this helps and if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create an Activity.
Using Eclipse or Android Studio you can use the wizard to create a simple blank Activity. Default name is usually MainActivity.
And in the generated main_activity.xml file, paste your above xml.
Now you have your main view.
I don't recommend you using `View Pagers` yet. You should get familiar with the android development first.
I remember that I started learning Android, I want to create a simple quiz game.
And this [tutorial](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.jp/2011/06/getting-started-complete-android-app.html) helped me a lot. 
 Grab the [complete source code](https://github.com/robhinds/AndroidChuckQuiz) and  go through it, and when you get stuck leave a comment.
Hope this will help.